# How to sort array inside object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

How do I sort an array after the x-value inside another object in state? I am tryng to sort the 'points' array

```
 state = {
        data: [
          {                                 
            color: "black", 
            points: [{x: 61, y: 54}, {x: 182, y: 49}, {x: 37, y: 35},
                     {x: 182, y: 61},{x: 13, y: 73},{x: 173, y: 59}]
        }],
    };
```

This is not working :

```
this.state.data.sort((a, b) => (a.points[0] > b.points[0]) ? 1 : -1);
```

I try to use this sort in a function and change the state

Comment: [.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is in place (mutates the object) and [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state) say mutating the state directly can give unexpected results.

Comment: It won’t update the view for starters. should be “this.setState(state => [...state.data.sort(..)])”. Another problem is that points[0] is an object, it cannot be compared.

Answer (score 1):

## Issues

1. `array.prototype.sort` is an in-place sort, which means it will simply mutate state. You should ***never*** directly manipulate state (i.e. `this.state.data`).
2. `points` array elements are also objects so they can't be compared directly, but their properties can be used.

## Solution

You should use a functional state update and shallow copy each level of your state object you intend to update.

```
sortData = () => {
  this.setState((state) => ({
    ...state, // <-- copy existing state
    // slice the existing data array to copy it, then call sort
    // access the `x` property of the first point object
    data: state.data.slice().sort((a, b) => a.points[0].x - b.points[0].x)
  }));
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-sort-array-inside-object-in-react]

If you meant that you wanted to sort the points instead of the data, the process is similar. Copy each level of state, then copy the array you want to update by sorting.

```
sortPoints = () => {
  this.setState((state) => ({
    ...state,
    data: state.data.map((dataItem) => ({
      ...dataItem,
      points: dataItem.points.slice().sort((a, b) => a.x - b.x)
    }))
  }));
};
```